# Implementing a parallel evaluation queue for Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I want to execute long running functions in parallel within a Jupyter notebook, without blocking the notebook itself. However, I also want to add completely unrelated jobs to the queue at any time, even while the queue is still processing previous jobs. Basically, this would be analogous to an extremely simple version of the kind of job schedulers used for compute clusters.

My current implementation is something like this. First create a pool of workers and a job queue.

```
import multiprocessing
def worker(job_queue, result_queue):
    while True:
        job = job_queue.get()
        function, args, kwargs = job
        result = function(*args, **kwargs)
        result_queue.put(result)
job_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
result_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2, initializer=worker, initargs=[job_queue, result_queue])
```

Later, in a separate cell, we define a function that takes a long time to evaluate, so we want to run it without blocking the notebook

```
def slow_function(x):
    import time
    time.sleep(3)
    return x+1
```

then we send several jobs to the queue to execute in parallel in the background

```
job_queue.put([slow_function, [1], {}])
job_queue.put([slow_function, [2], {}])
```

Then, while the previous jobs are still running, we define another function, and add that to the queue as well

```
def complex_function(x):
    return slow_function(x)*2
job_queue.put([complex_function, [1], {}])
job_queue.put([complex_function, [2], {}])
```

We continue running other things in the Jupyter notebook for a while, then after all the jobs are finished, we get the results

```
result1 = result_queue.get(False)
result2 = result_queue.get(False)
result3 = result_queue.get(False)
result4 = result_queue.get(False)
```

That is the general workflow, I want to be able to do.

## Problems

As implemented, after pool creation, the worker processes immediately crash and relaunch in an infinite loop, with pickle errors

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'worker' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\yy51\AppData\Local\Programs\Miniconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 122, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\yy51\AppData\Local\Programs\Miniconda3\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 132, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If I switch to using `pathos` using `pool = pathos.multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2, initializer=worker, initargs=[job_queue, result_queue])`, then I get `RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance`

I can kind of get it working if I replace `multiprocessing.Queue` with `pathos` queues `pathos.helpers.mp.Queue`

```
job_queue = pathos.helpers.mp.Queue()
result_queue = pathos.helpers.mp.Queue()
```

But it still doesn't work if I try to call another defined function within `complex_function`

```
job_queue.put([complex_function, [1], {}])

NameError: name 'slow_function' is not defined
```

## Restrictions

I also really, really, do not want to create a separate file to host `slow_function` or `complex_function` in a module, as it would be massively inconvenient for interactive notebook usage.

I'd also want to define new functions *after* creating the process pool. (I'm aware sometimes it's easier to define functions before the pool)

Note: I'm running this on Windows.

Comment: kind of goes against how I've ever thought of notebooks working!  maybe you could use `ayncio.run_in_executor` along with an `ipywidgets.Output` widget to keep everything in one cell and let it continue running in the background?

Comment: Yea, it does feel like I'm kind of fighting against the system.

Comment: I eventually just gave up and started using ipyparallel

Answer (score 0):

Have had a play, and this is sort of what my comment is about:

```
import sys
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures

import ipywidgets

threadpool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(4)

def run(fn, *args, **kwds):
    "run fn in threadpool"
    out = ipywidgets.Output()

    def print(*args, file=sys.stdout):
        line = ' '.join(map(str, args)) + '\n'
        if file is sys.stderr:
            out.append_stderr(line)
        else:
            out.append_stdout(line)

    def done(fut: asyncio.Future):
        try:
            result = fut.result()
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print("cancelled", fut, file=sys.stderr)
        except Exception:
            print("failed", fut, file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            print("completed", fut)

    async def go():
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        return await loop.run_in_executor(
            threadpool,
            lambda: fn(print, *args, **kwds),
        )

    task = asyncio.create_task(go())
    task.add_done_callback(done)

    return out
```

The idea is to call `run` with some non-asyncio / blocking code, like:

```
import time

def cpu_bound(print, dt, fail=False):
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(dt)
        print(i, time.time())
    if fail:
        1 / 0
    return "done"

run(cpu_bound, 0.1)
```

The `print` that comes in is to allow output to go to the right place, the `Output` widget seems to rely on asyncio magic to have the "real" `print` going to the right place.  It adds a completion callback so that it can output something on completion, like the method failing as in:

```
run(cpu_bound, 0.5, fail=True)
```

It looks kind of neat having a few cells running `run(cpu_bound, 1)` in each.  The output just accumulates as it's processed, hopefully this is somewhat similar to what you intended!

Comment: I like the idea, but is it possible to make it work with `ProcessPoolExecutor` instead? I really do need multi-process

Comment: You're free to modify the code to do that if you want!  Not sure if you care about the output going anywhere sensible, but it would likely require a `Queue` to make sure the strings ends up in the right process